# Php error EOF>>> Unexpected end;

Tags: php, eof

I'm trying to create a login page with EOF output but I get error at line 29, and at this line there is nothing I think its expecting some symbol or something.
This is the code:

```
<?php
    require_once 'config.php';
    if(logged_in()) {header('Location: index.php');}
    $title = "login";
    $nonav = true;
    $mini = true;
    if($_POST && (!empty($_POST['username']) ) && (!empty($_POST['password']))) {
        validate_user($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
    }
    $error = $_SESSION['error'];
    $content = <<<EOF
    $error
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <p>
            <label for="username">username:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="username" class="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password">password:</label><br />
            <input type="password" name="password" class="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="login" />
        </p>
    </form>
    EOF;
    include 'layout.php'; ?>
```

Some ideas where is the mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

`EOF;` cannot have space before it. It needs to be first on the line.